# Does any historical precedent suggest that the Romans would tolerate Paul's crusade in Acts 9:1-2, because he got a Jewish priest's approval?

Tags: acts, history

Q. Does any historical precedent suggest that the Romans would tolerate Paul's crusade in Acts 9:1-2, because he got a Jewish priest's approval?

> [Act 9:1-2 NASB95] [1] Now Saul, still breathing threats and murder against the disciples of the Lord, **went to the high priest, [2] and asked for letters from him to the synagogues at Damascus, so that if he found any belonging to the Way, both men and women, he might bring them bound to Jerusalem.**

Comment: 13 gold badges and a reputation score of '1'. Is that some kind of record? Looking forward to here more from the Ruminator once he gets out of the doghouse.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if the precedent was Ezra ch7 vv25-26, where Ezra has delegated authority over all those of his own religion in the province "Beyond the River" (which is, of course, named from the Persian viewpoint and is roughly the equivalent of the Roman Syria).

The Sanhedrin were claiming a similar authority over Paul himself once he had been arrested, complaining that he was an agitator "among all the Jews throughout the world" (Acts ch24 v5).

Comment: There might be an allusion in there somewhere, but what I'm seeking is some evidence that Saul/Paul could get license from a Jew that would allow him to persecute people based on their devotion to a "King" that they crucified.

Comment: The Romans let the Jews govern their own religious affairs. From a Jewish viewpoint, a letter from the high priest would be a legal authority. On that basis the agent (a judge of 'gezerot') would be empowered to act as a kind of magistrate. Bringing them back to be tried in Jerusalem does seem unprecedented but not out of the question.

Comment: @Stephen Disraeli, FYI, I upvoted this post because I'm ever looking for what passage from the Jewish scriptures (not just Tanach), and yours is the first, reasonable candidate. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably. The Romans allowed the Temple guards to arrest Jesus in the Gospels and according to the [Jewish Encyclopedia](https://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/12239-police-laws) Jewish religious courts also maintained local police forces. Bringing people back in chains to Jerusalem is most problematic part of the scenario.

**Pre-Roman times**

> There are many terms in the Bible which have been translated to denote
> magistrates or police officers; but the correctness of the translation
> is questioned.... The Deuteronomic code (Deut. xvi. 18) enjoins the
> appointment of "shoṭerim"(LXX. γραμματοεισαγωγεὶς...) whose
> duty it was to execute the decisions of the court. The frequent mention of the shoṭerim together with the judges (Deut. xvi. 18; Josh. viii. 33, xxiii. 2, xxiv. 1; I Chron. xxiii. 4, xxvi. 29), or with the elders of the community (Num. xi. 16; Deut. xxix. 9, xxxi. 28) who acted as judges in earlier times, would seem to indicate that these officials were attached to the courts of justice, and held themselves in readiness to execute the orders of the officiating judge.

**Second Temple times**

> The Temple had a police force of its own, most of its officers being
> Levites. These were the gatekeepers ("sho'arim"; I Chron. ix. 17,
> 24-27, xxvi. 12-18), the watchmen that guarded the entrance to the
> Temple mount, and those that had charge of the cleaning of its
> precincts... The Mishnah (Ket. xiii. 1) mentions two judges of
> "gezerot" (lit. "prohibitions," "decrees"), who were in Jerusalem
> during the latter part of the second commonwealth...  it is safe to
> assume that the functions of these judges were similar to those of
> modern police magistrates...

The Second Jewish Commonwealth here refers to the period between the last third of the sixth century B.C.E. to the destruction of the Second Temple by the Romans in 70 CE. So the above paragraph includes the time that the OP asks about. Also, according to [Joshua Kulp](https://www.sefaria.org/English_Explanation_of_Mishnah_Shabbat.1.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) the *gezerot* should be understood as "prohibitions created to prevent a situation which might cause a person to transgress."

**Conclusion**: If Paul were employed as the agent of the high priest or a religious court as a judge of *gezerot,* then there is possible precedent that his activities would be allowed by Roman authorities. The report that Paul "went to the high priest and asked him for letters to the synagogues in Damascus" could be Luke's way of expressing Paul's getting hired as judge of *gezerot* assigned to Damascus. On the other hand, there is no known evidence outside of the NT that the high priest or any Jewish court ordered that Jewish Christians be arrested and brought back for trial in Jerusalem. Normally violations of *gezerot* would be handled locally. Nevertheless if the letters of the high priest constituted a decree aimed at preventing a major transgression such as blasphemy, the answer is "yes" that the Romans would tolerate such actions by Paul.

Comment: The High Priest and the rest of the Temple leaders were all Sadducees. Paul was a Pharisee. The Sadducees had control of the Temple, but they did not run the Empire and did not speak for the Pharisees, who ran the Synagogues. The Sadducees did not believe in resurrection, but the Pharisees did (because the Sadducees' canon was, like the Samaritans, just the Torah. I think the whole account lacks credibility at many levels.

Comment: And don't get me started on Luke's other political fantasy, regarding a tax registry where everyone in the Empire has return to their ancestral home; patently false on the face of it.

Comment: All relevant and helpful (+1), but completely unhistorical. The chief priest was a Sadducee, while the synagogues were of the Pharisees. They were bitter rivals. See Acts 23:3-10. Also, Paul is said to have been raised by Gamaliel, whose position was more "live and let live."

Comment: My conclusion was specifically conditioned on the supposed fact that Paul was cooperating with the high priest. Pharisees and Sadducees could at times cooperate against each other when they had a common enemy -- and this does seem to be the case here. (remembering that the Pharisees were hardly monolithic.)

Comment: Another example of cooperation between the two camps: Josephus says that the high priests coalesced with Pharisees of the peace party to try to prevent the Jewish Revolt in 66. Ironically, this may have brought them into a potential alliance with Christians. But the opposite was the case at the time in question. Paul's being "raised" by Gamaliel is indeed an mystery in this drama.